# Time Machine from TC ko on MAvericks

Tags: backup, restore, time-capsule, macos

Just installed mavericks, erasing the hard drive and installing it as brand new; then I wanted to restore my backup from Time machine (as I always did) but an error screen appears, saying "impossible to open every backup".
I'm kinda scared, I don't have other backups and I always considered time machine on Time capsule as reliable.
What can I do? I tried both from the startup of the new os and inside Mavericks, from migration assistan..
please help!! I have my whole iphoto library on it..

Answer (score 1):

It's still there. At the very least, you can manually connect to your Time Capsule by browsing to it in the finder. You'll then have access to all the backups, and you can manually browse your old hard drive and restore things by copying them over from your home folder.